# Android JB skia api/operation list

Tags: android, graphics, skia

I noticed the following explanation in Android developer official website,

"
we anticipate Skia to be slowly phased out without adverse effects to developers. Skia is currently deprecated and in maintenance mode but will be neccessary for a while because most apps published today still rely on non-hardware accelerated Canvas operations. In addition, not all Skia operations are supported by OpenGL, so some operations are still done in software with Skia, even with hardware acceleration turned on.
"

Will that be any list available to tell me what operations are still being used in Android JB graphic part via skia?

I am sure any reference will be useful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is available in the chart on the [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) page  on the Android Developer site.

For more background you can watch the Google IO session on Hardware Rendering:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/accelerated-android-rendering.html

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer Chang.

Comment: about the Hardware Acceleration, can i take the table shown in the link as, for example, in Canvas api, drawPicture() can only be implemented via skia but OpenGL (API level 18)? And the same story for Paint, Xfermode and Shader.

Comment: I don't think drawPicture() is supported. You probably mean drawBitMapMesh() has Hardware Acceleration on API 18, that is how I'm reading it.

Comment: In API 18, the Hardware Acceleration supports drawBitMapMesg(). This means that the implementation will go the OpenGL route. However, drawPicture() can only go skia route since it is not yet supported by hardware acceleration.
Plus, most of Paint(except some are checked), Xfermode and Shader are not yet supported by Hardware acceleration so they can only be used via skia lib. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Honestly, I'm just reading the document. You can always create a test app or look at the source if you really want to know what is happening.